# Overwrite CSS from another files

Tags: html, css, fonts

I've downloaded a big webtemplate with many different css and js files. Now my website looks good but there still some little things I want to change. Like the font-style, colors and other things.

Now my problem is that I'm not able to overwrite the css from another files.

I want to change the font-family of my webpage. Now the normal content inside my

tags, the navbar and and and... they all got the new font-family. But every  tag still got the old font family. I tried it with:

```
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important;
```

but this haven't changed a thing and I don't really want to overwrite the css files that came from the template.

is there a way that my custom.css gets more important then the other files? Or any other trick?

Comment: can you send the url of your website

Comment: show your code or provide your working url?

Comment: And which selector are you using? `? {font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important;}`

Comment: Also add your custom CSS after the downloaded one

Comment: Are you implement google font? or font-face

Comment: okay wait a seccond... - oh and the selector i'm using is: body { ...  }

Comment: First try applying this georgia font style. See if it works,then try implementing other font-styles. I think your code is not executing at all because of any syntax error.

Comment: @WellNo i wrote you answer, change selector. if you use body, it does not affect all nodes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your selector to

```
* {font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to overwrite the css file, you have to find the class or the id of the elements you want to change in the css file of the template that you downloaded, then you can change it.

Comment: you mean if there is a class - like " .test " - in the downloaded css file - I need to take the " .test " class in my custom.css to overwrite the css?

Comment: If you want to change the class ".test" css, you open the downloaded css file of your template and find that class (ctrl - F), then you can change the css property that you want instead of creating a new css file or overwriting it.

Comment: yeah but I dont want to overwrite the orginal file - I want to overwrite the css propertys on a additional file